# USB-C Power Delivery can charge only at 65W even though the adapter is 100W

Tags: power-management, adapter, usb-c, charging

I am using 100W (20 Volt * 5 Amps) power delivery over USB-C to charge my laptop. When I write the `sensors` command this is what I get:

```
ucsi_source_psy_USBC000:001-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
in0:          20.00 V  (min =  +5.00 V, max = +20.00 V)
curr1:         3.25 A  (max =  +5.00 A)
```

Does anyone know how to get **max =  +5.00 A** (100W)? I am somehow limited to 3.25 Amps only (65W).

Edit:
adding this photo to provide more information on the `sensors` command:
[image]